# text goes out of paragraph css html

Tags: html, css

I have text inside a paragraph

```html
<p style="width:200px;">Text goes here</p>
```

My problem is that when the text grows (bigger width), it doesn't go to a new line. Instead, the text goes out of the paragraph. How can I force the text to continue on a new line if it grows.

Comment: This works perfectly in IE, Firefox, Chrome... There's probably something else interfering with this simple code.

Comment: i'm testing with chrome.

Comment: Yeah, and like I said and some answers too, there is definitely something interfering with your paragraph element, copy-pasted as it is here, it works just fine. As a proof : http://jsfiddle.net/CPy5E/

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

to the CSS

Comment: Or remove not breakable spaces from the text itself

Answer (score 5):

I believe that there is more to this than just that p tag.  I recommend you look at your css for the site and see if something is changing either the `overflow` or `word-wrap` attributes.

http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/

http://www.css3.com/css-overflow/

Comment: is correct if you want the text to wrap line by line within a set width styled element you will want to utilize the word-wrap css property he/she mentioned.

Comment: @Infotekka in this case http://jsfiddle.net/Vivekranth/Ah6fb/28/ i need the text to came on next line while over flow is that possible

Answer (score 4):

remove the width on the p tag sir.

```
<p>Text goes here.</p>
```

If you can't remove the width try adding the white-space attribute

```
<p style="width:200px;white-space:pre;>Lot's of text here that will be wider than 200px</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default overflow is auto which should should make it go to the next line. Perhaps somewhere else you set `overflow: hidden`; which is why it does that. Try setting `overflow:auto` again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CSS3 : word-wrap: break-word; 
Because if you have a long word in the paragraph it will always get out of the element, for example : try

```
<p style="width:100px;"> loremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsum </p> 
<p style="width:100px; word-wrap:break-word;"> loremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsum </p>
```

Overflow will make the text invisible .

Answer (score 0):

Add

> white-space:wrap;

to the style. That should do the trick.

Comment: This is an invalid parameter to pass to white-space.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [CSS `word-break` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) is one way to do it:

```html
<p style="word-break:break-all; width:200px;">
This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because almost all elements in HTML are boxes , you can fix your "p tag" into its div like this

```
<p style="position:relative; width:95%; height:whatever%;" > content </p>
```

You can also achieve text-indention by positioning the box using "css left or right" property.

```
<p style="position:relative; width:95%; height:whatever%; left:20px;" > content </p>
```

Note : Do not forget "css position property" before positioning any box.